# How can I show data types in a Visio database diagram

Tags: database, microsoft-visio, documentation

How can I display the column types in a Visio database diagram?

Comment: Which version of Visio are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[See Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/display-data-types-in-a-database-model-diagram-HP001208435.aspx):

> **Display data types in a database model diagram**
>
> 1. Open the database model diagram.
> 2. On the **Database** menu, point to **Options**, and then click **Document**.
> 3. In the **Database Document Options** dialog box, click the **Table** tab, and then, under **Data Types**, click **Show physical** or **Show portable**.
> 4. Click **OK**.